# XeTeX: polyglossia & \textarabic: some punctuation symbols appear as boxes

Tags: xetex, pdf, polyglossia, arabic

I use XeLaTex on Xubuntu with polyglosia to write arabic, but characters like parenthesis, brackets, etc appear as white boxes in the final pdf produced.

I have a minimal working example. With the Cordoba font the parentheses appear but the letters arenn't connect, so something else must be going on there.

I don't know if this is a problem with xelatex, with font configuration, or sth else. Any help would be appreciated!

It requires the fonts (deb package names `fonts-droid`, `fonts-hosny-amiri`, `fonts-kacst`).

[image: Pdf from XeLaTeX]

(MWE updated after comments, changes in my github repo [`vkatsikaros/stackoverflow-tex-309313`](https://github.com/vkatsikaros/stackoverflow-tex-309313)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Droid Arabic Naskh}

\begin{document}

lalala

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Droid Arabic Naskh}
\textarabic{ (كَبير) }

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{KacstBook}
\textarabic{ (كَبير) }

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Cortoba}
\textarabic{ (كَبير) }

\end{document}
```

The same text with same fonts, from LibreOffice Writer renders in pdf properly:

[image: What it should look like - from LibreOffice Writer]

### Update

Indeed as Thérèse mentioned the font doesn't have the parenthesis :(
Fontforge:

[image: screenshot]

PS 1. I don't want to use `ArabTex`, because I find it very hard to write and correct it.

PS 2. I opened the files on windows machines too, but the result renders in the same way.

References:

Xelatex:

```
$ xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3-2014012222 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 SIL International and Jonathan Kew.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 52.1; using 52.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.8; using 1.2.8
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.5.2; using 2.5.2
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.2.4; using 1.3.6
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 0.9.25; using 0.9.27
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.11.0; using 2.11.0
Compiled with libpng version 1.2.49; using 1.2.50
Compiled with poppler version 0.24.5
```

Ubuntu:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: I haven’t yet installed Droid Arabic or taken the time to examine it, but note that `cm-default` is obsolete as an option to `fontspec` (is your `fontspec` recent?), and that you should add the option `[Script=Arabic]` when defining `\arabicfont` in order to get Arabic shaping.

Comment: Droid Arabic Naskh and Kacst Book do not have ordinary parentheses, but there are ornate parentheses at FD3E and FD3F.  (LibreOffice is taking the missing glyphs from another font.) By the way, `polyglossia` loads `fontspec`, so you don’t need `usepackage{fontspec}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thérèse explained what happens (see comment and question's update section). The font doesn't have the simple parenthesis.

A workaround I used for this: defined an english (the main language of the document) parenthesis with `\textenglish` to force the parenthesis from the [Unicode Block "Basic Latin"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/basic_latin/list.htm) `LEFT PARENTHESIS (U+0028)` and `RIGHT PARENTHESIS (U+0029)` to be used. Then the parenthesis are picked by whatever is the default font being used in the document.

So the end result looks as I would like it to be :

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Droid Arabic Naskh}

% manually add english parentheses around argument
\newcommand{\prth}[1]{\textenglish{)}#1\textenglish{(}}

\begin{document}

lalala

\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Droid Arabic Naskh}
\textarabic{ \prth{كَبير} }

\newfontfamily\arabicfont{KacstBook}
\textarabic{ \prth{كَبير} }

\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Cortoba}
\textarabic{ (كَبير) }

\end{document}
```